# Windows standby memory build up when writing to file

Tags: c++, windows

I'm writing an appliction in C++ that has to write big files (up to 100GB) to SSD disk. It runs on Windows 10. I'm using std::fstream for file write. The problem is that during that process Windows's standby memory increases to unreasonble amounts: it becomes roughly equal to the amount of data currently written to disk, and build up with it. When this amount reaches the size of computer's RAM (64 Gb), the whole system begins to lag  tremendously which affects perfomance. The speed is important for the application since it obtains source data in real time from hardware unit. It is worth noticing that the data is in fact gets written to file, so there's no need (as far as I can see) to store it in RAM. Also, the application's RAM consumption remains steady at 25 Mb, so there seems to be no memory leak.
If I use external tool like EmptyStandbyList.exe during the process to wipe the system's standby memory, then everything works smoothly.
If I comment out the file writting code, then the memory does not build up.
The anti-malware software is disabled.

This situation can be reproduced using the following toy example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>

static const size_t data_size = 1024 * 1024;

struct Packet
{
    char data[data_size];
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    uint64_t packet = 0;
    std::ofstream out("buffer", std::ios_base::binary);
    while (true)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Packet> ptr = std::make_shared<Packet>();
        out.write(ptr->data, data_size);
        packet++;
        if (packet % 1024 == 0)
        {
            std::cout << packet << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

(I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.)

So, the question is: is there any way to avoid this memory build-up?

Comment: Is there any reason you are recreating the buffer (`ptr`) every the time round the loop?

Comment: Standby memory in Windows are cached pages that may be reused at any time. Are you sure that high standby consumption and the system lagging at the same time are not just a coincidence? edit: on my system, using your example, standby consumption doesn't increase at all.

Comment: @Richard Critten, It mirrors the way memory is managed in actual app. A packet is obtained via network in a separate thread, then thread provides  shared_ptr that goes through a pipeline of handlers to be finally written to a file. I dont' think that the actual way the packet is stored matters here.

Comment: @Pezo, Yes, I'm afraid I'm sure. The lag appears exactly when the size of obtained data (and standby memory consumption) reaches 64 Gb. If I use an external tool like EmptyStandbyList.exe, then the process goes smoothly.

Comment: That's strange, can you try with a newer version of VS? I used VS2017.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/976618/you-experience-performance-issues-in-applications-and-services-when-th), could be fixed [with this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965240(v=vs.85).aspx).  Be sure to eliminate possible environmental issues, disable anti-malware first.

Comment: @Pezo, I'm afraid I dont currently have disk space on my work machine for another VS build, and, ultimetely, this project has to be built in VS2013, so the solution has to work there.

Comment: @HansPassant, the anti-malware was disabled. I'll add thta info to the qestion.

Comment: While you're running the test, keep Windows Explorer closed - i.e. don't try to visually monitor the file size. I found that once the file gets to a certain size, Windows starts to have a lot trouble loading the disk info while data writes are buffered. The "free" memory will still go down, but that shouldn't matter. Interestingly, for me the "free" memory doesn't get released until I manually delete the file.

Comment: @BlairFonville, That's an interesting effect. During my tests Windows Explorer is usually closed --- it does not seem to matter in this case.

Comment: Could just be my system then; she’s getting up in age. The only other suggestion I have is to compile for x64 with LargeAddressAware enabled. And test as a release build. I know older VC versions had a problem with memory apparently leaking from the profiler.

Comment: for what you use std::fstream for file write file ? this is worst choice. use direct `WriteFile`. create file with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` and `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN`. set valid data size at begin, if it known. or `FileAllocationInfo` info. .always good use asynchronous io for file

Comment: @RbMm, do I understans correctly that FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING implies that each data chunk that FileWrite writes must have a size that is a multiplier of the volume sector size? That's rather hard restriction in my case, since my application writes different amount of data each time. Still, I guess I can try this.

Comment: @Month - yes, for `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` you need query first file sector size and write multiple sectors. however not hard implement this yourself, if once allocate buffer of sector size and cache data in this buffer. also you can try and without `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`. but not use any fstream. this is the worst choice. only direct `WriteFile` and better asynchronous. also very important preallocate file size at begin